# MySQL syntax error 1064 for "SELECT * FROM System"

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql v8.0 and I'm having a syntax error for a simple command like this:

`SELECT * FROM System`

Then I have an error like this:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'System
select * from System' at line 1`

But if I change my command to

`SELECT * FROM someSchema.System`
it works.

My colleagues said they have no problem of `SELECT * FROM System` but their MySql version is 5.7.

I'd like to see if this is a version change between MySql 5.7 and 8.0 or there is some setting for my MySql setup? How can I avoid explicitly writing my schema name?

Comment: As of recently, `SYSTEM` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S). You must quote it in backticks to use it as a table name: `\`System\``

Comment: [System](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S) is a reserved keyword in mysql 8.0.3+ . Try 'SELECT * FROM ` System `'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System` is a reserved word, try with

`` SELECT * FROM `System` ``